# Why is a multi dimensional array with one array different than more than one array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure if I phrased this correctly, but basically, I have two arrays (see below). The first array only has one "segment" array, but when doing a var_dump, it shows an array of it's children (or not at all).

The bigger array has multiple "segment" arrays, and in the var_dump, you can see the array(5).

Background is I am getting these two array from a json string that I decode in php.

Here are the arrays:
Json:

```
{ "css": { "segment": { "type": "Body", "comments": "Launch Pad v4 theme.css", "rule": { "selector": "html", "declaration": [ { "property": "margin", "value": "0" }, { "property": "padding", "value": "0" }, { "property": "height", "value": "100%" }, { "property": "background", "value": "#fff url(body_bg.gif) repeat-x top" } ] } } } }
```

Array:

```
    array(1) {
  ["css"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["segment"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "Body"
      ["comments"]=>
      string(23) " v4 theme.css"
      ["rule"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["selector"]=>
        string(4) "html"
        ["declaration"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["property"]=>
            string(6) "margin"
            ["value"]=>
            string(1) "0"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["property"]=>
            string(7) "padding"
            ["value"]=>
            string(1) "0"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["property"]=>
            string(6) "height"
            ["value"]=>
            string(4) "100%"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(2) {
            ["property"]=>
            string(10) "background"
            ["value"]=>
            string(34) "#fff url(body_bg.gif) repeat-x top"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Json:

```
{ "css": { "segment": [ { "type": "Body", "comments": "Launch Pad v4 theme.css", "rule": [ { "selector": "html", "declaration": [ { "property": "margin", "value": "0" }, { "property": "padding", "value": "0" }, { "property": "height", "value": "100%" }, { "property": "background", "value": "#fff url(body_bg.gif) repeat-x top" } ] }, { "selector": "body", "declaration": [ { "property": "font", "value": "12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" }, { "property": "line-height", "value": "1.35", "comments": "Specify default line height as a pure number value (no px/em)...adjusting the value as desired. This will allow the line-height to flex depending on what size the user specifies their text within the rich text editor" }, { "property": "color", "value": "#333" } ] } ] }, { "type": "Fonts/Typography", "comments": "Fonts/Typography" }, { "type": "Header" }, { "type": "Content" }, { "type": "Footer" } ] } }
```

Array

```
array(1) {
      ["css"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["segment"]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(4) "Body"
            ["comments"]=>
            string(23) "theme.css"
            ["rule"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["selector"]=>
                string(4) "html"
                ["declaration"]=>
                array(4) {
                  [0]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(6) "margin"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(1) "0"
                  }
                  [1]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(7) "padding"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(1) "0"
                  }
                  [2]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(6) "height"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(4) "100%"
                  }
                  [3]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(10) "background"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(34) "#fff url(body_bg.gif) repeat-x top"
                  }
                }
              }
              [1]=>
              array(2) {
                ["selector"]=>
                string(4) "body"
                ["declaration"]=>
                array(3) {
                  [0]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(4) "font"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(33) "12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
                  }
                  [1]=>
                  array(3) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(11) "line-height"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(4) "1.35"
                    ["comments"]=>
                    string(216) "Specify default line height as a pure number value (no px/em)...adjusting the value as desired. This will allow the line-height to flex depending on what size the user specifies their text within the rich text editor"
                  }
                  [2]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["property"]=>
                    string(5) "color"
                    ["value"]=>
                    string(4) "#333"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(16) "Fonts/Typography"
            ["comments"]=>
            string(16) "Fonts/Typography"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(1) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(6) "Header"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(1) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(7) "Content"
          }
          [4]=>
          array(1) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(6) "Footer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

My question is how can I force a array when there is only 1 array in the "segment", or why is that even happening?

Edit:

What I am asking is this, why is it in the smaller array, there is only one "segment" array and I do a count on it, shows 3. It shows "comments", "type", and array "rules" which are all children of "segment". Now in the bigger array, where there are more than 1 "segment" rows, the count is 5, and each "segment" has an array with "comments", "type", and array "rules", not as direct children.

Comment: Could you share the json string as well?

Comment: Could you post the json string you're receiving?

Comment: @JayD. your `JSON` contains value inside value and because of that it creates a `multidimensional array`.

Comment: @JayD. Everything works exactly as it is supposed to. var_dump represents the array that way because that is what the json string means.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the var_dump values. It states there is one segment with 5 type values, not 5 segments.

Comment: I edited to hopefully make some more sense.